Why is this code throwing random "file is being used by another process" exceptions?
.NET 4.8 VS 2019
I have a class in my program that logs text to a file to log command activity and free text messages.  The program is crashing for one (1) customer of tens of thousands with a "file is being used by another process" exception in the "LogFreeText" method.  However, I cannot seem to figure out the issue.
Here is the class, which is embedded in the command handler class I wrote:
Public Class CommandLogger

    Private _sFileName As String = ""

    Public LockObject As New Object()

    Public ReadOnly Property LogFile As String
        Get
            Return _sFileName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(sFolder As String)
        'Clear old Activity Logs
        Dim directory As New IO.DirectoryInfo(sFolder)

        SyncLock (LockObject)
            For Each file As IO.FileInfo In directory.GetFiles
                If file.Name.StartsWith(My.Application.Info.ProductName.Trim.ToUpper & "_CMDLOG_") AndAlso file.Name.EndsWith(".TXT") Then
                    If (Now - file.CreationTime).Days > 7 Then file.Delete()
                End If
            Next

            _sFileName = sFolder & "\" & My.Application.Info.ProductName.Trim.ToUpper & "_CMDLOG_" & Format(Now, "yyyy_MM_dd_H_mm_ss") & ".TXT"
            If File.Exists(_sFileName) Then
                FileSystem.RenameFile(_sFileName, _sFileName.Replace(".TXT", "_OLD.TXT"))
            End If
            Using log As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(_sFileName)
                log.WriteLine("DateTime|CommandVerb|Page|Key|String|Text")
                log.WriteLine(Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss") & "|STARTUP||||")
                log.Close()
            End Using
        End SyncLock

    End Sub

    Public Sub LogCommand(mnc As MBFS_CommonControls.MBFSNavCommand)
        SyncLock (LockObject)
            If Not File.Exists(_sFileName) Then
                Using log As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(_sFileName)
                    log.WriteLine("DateTime|CommandVerb|Page|Key|String|Text")
                    log.WriteLine(Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss") & "|STARTUP-ORPHAN|||||")
                    log.Close()
                End Using
            End If
            Using log As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(_sFileName)
                log.WriteLine(Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss") & "|" & mnc.CommandVerb.Trim & "|" & mnc.CommandPage.ToString.Trim & "|" & mnc.RecordKey.ToString.Trim & "|" & mnc.RecordParentKey.ToString.Trim & "|" & mnc.sStringArgument.Trim & "|" & mnc.Text.Trim)
                log.Close()
            End Using
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Public Sub LogFreeText(sText As String)
        SyncLock (LockObject)
            If Not File.Exists(_sFileName) Then
                Using log As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(_sFileName)
                    log.WriteLine("DateTime|CommandVerb|Page|Key|String|Text")
                    log.WriteLine(Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss") & "|STARTUP-ORPHAN|||||")
                    log.Close()
                End Using
            End If
            Using log As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(_sFileName) 
                log.WriteLine(Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss") & "|Freetext: " & sText & "|||||")  '<<<<<<< BOOM!
                log.Close()
            End Using
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Public Function Closeout() As Boolean
        LogFreeText(Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss") & "|SHUTDOWN||||")
        Return True
    End Function

End Class

In case it helps, here is the stack trace, with private identifying info redacted...
Message: The process cannot access the file 'C:\ProgramData\MyCompany\MyProgram\MyProgram_CMDLOG_2024_12_15_12_53_35.TXT' because it is being used by another process.
Stack Trace: 
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append)
   at System.IO.File.AppendText(String path)
   at MyClass.CommonGlobalWinFuncs.CommandLogger.LogFreeText(String sText)
   at MyClass.CommonGlobalWinFuncs.DoCommand(MyNavCommand& mncCommand, String& sErr)
   at MyClass.CommonGlobalWinFuncs.CommandShuffler(MBFSNavCommand mnc)
   at MyClass.ActiveWindow.HandleShowEntityCommand(Object sender, String sCommand, EventArgs e, wwCommandAction& eResponseAction)
   at MyClass.A_ModalWorkWithForm.SelectGridRow(Int32 iRow)
   at MyClass.A_ModalWorkWithForm.wwGrid_RowEnter(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnRowEnter(DataGridViewCell& dataGridViewCell, Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean canCreateNewRow, Boolean validationFailureOccurred)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetCurrentCellAddressCore(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SetAndSelectCurrentCellAddress(Int32 columnIndex, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean setAnchorCellAddress, Boolean validateCurrentCell, Boolean throughMouseClick, Boolean clearSelection, Boolean forceCurrentCellSelection)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.MakeFirstDisplayedCellCurrentCell(Boolean includeNewRow)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam) 
No Inner Exception found. 

I wrap all of the streamwriters in using blocks as is my habit.
I close the stream at all points where I write a line.  See Code.
No other class exists that tries to write to that file name.
The class is invoked by only one process.
I don't think that there is threading involved, but out of an abundance of caution I wrapped the functions in SyncLock.
This happens for one customer.  There is a random number of successful writes and then this happens.  I cannot make it happen here.
I am totally confused.  Am I missing something?
Thanks

Does this one customer have and drive monitoring, or write monitoring, software getting upset with the volume of reads/writes and locking it up? Or possibly one of these would be an option? https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Andrew I will ask the customer if she has any drive monitoring. My support pack also sends extracts of the windows application log and I will look there as well.

I fixed the issue for this customer by brute force.
I isolated the writes into a single method.
I wrapped the method into a try block.
I put in a catch which tested for the error message in question.
If the error was caught it added the line to the end of a list of strings.
If no error, I test for any strings in the list, and write those first, and then the pending new string.  This ensures no loss of logging data (assuming no other crash before it writes).
Here's the code:
    Private Sub TextWrite(sText As String)
        Try
            SyncLock (LockObject)
                If Not File.Exists(_sFileName) Then
                    Using log As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(_sFileName)
                        log.WriteLine("DateTime|CommandVerb|Page|Key|String|Text")
                        log.WriteLine(Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss") & "|STARTUP-ORPHAN|||||")
                        log.WriteLine(sText)
                        log.Close()
                    End Using
                Else
                    Using log As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(_sFileName)
                        '' If there are unwritten lines write them.
                        If lBufferUnwritten.Count > 0 Then
                            For Each s As String In lBufferUnwritten
                                log.WriteLine(s)
                            Next
                            lBufferUnwritten.Clear()
                        End If
                        log.WriteLine(sText)
                        log.Close()
                    End Using
                End If
            End SyncLock
        Catch ex As Exception
            If ex.Message.ToUpper().Contains("ANOTHER PROCESS") Then
                lBufferUnwritten.Add(Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss") & "|BUFFERED - FILE ANOTHER PROCESS|||||")
                lBufferUnwritten.Add(sText)
            Else
                Throw
            End If
        End Try
    End Sub

So there seems to be some sort of anomaly which needs to be coded around, and this is the only code-around I found that works.
